# Navigate to screen based on remember me status stored in shared preference in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a simple android app with flutter. When users sign-in and if the remember me checkbox is true, then the user should navigate to the dashboard screen. For this in `main.dart` file I wrote this Future builder code like this.

```
class  MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
static String remember;
Future<String> _loadWidget() async
{
  SharedPreferences preferences=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  remember = preferences.getString("keep_login");
        return remember;
}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        //primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(12, 127, 164, 1),
        primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(2, 136, 209, 1),
        accentColor: Colors.white,

      ),
      onGenerateRoute: Router().generateRoute,
      home:  FutureBuilder(
        future: _loadWidget(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
           if (snapshot.hasData) {
             if(snapshot.data == null)
             {
               return SignIn();
             }
             else
             {
               return snapshot.data == "no" ? SignIn() : Dashboard();
             }

           }

             return snapshot.data == null ? SignIn() : Scaffold(body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),));

         },
        )

    );
  }
}
```

Now when I open the app, for a few seconds my sigin page is displayed and then dashboard is rendered. How to overcome this, and once when I pop the dashboard screen app is not closing instead there is a black screen. Am I wrong some way. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the `ConnectionState` of in the `FutureBuilder`.
`AsyncSnapshot` has a connection state to inform you if the future is done, active or might even caused an error.

I recommend to check out the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) about `FutureBuilder` and the [Widget of the Week video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo), where they quickly address this connection state.

`snapshot.hasData` and `snapshot.data == null` are exactly the same.

```
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    if(snapshot.data == null) {
      return SignIn();
    } else {
      return snapshot.data == "no" ? SignIn() : Dashboard();
    }
  }
  return Scaffold(body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),));
},
```

Comment: You saved my day!.. I am new to flutter, what is that connectionstate can you brief  it.

Comment: I am getting a black screen while poping the dashboard screen. What should I do? @dumazy

Comment: I've added some more explanation and links to official documenation.
For the black screen when popping, I assume this is another issue, probably related to `onGenerateRoute`. Have a look there, maybe try with removing the `onGenerateRoute` first. If you're still stuck, I suggest to address this in a separate question

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `builder` function of the Future. You wait for the data and then decide, whether to show the `SignIn` page or the Dashboard. That's correct. But in the time, the future has no data you also show the `SignIn` page.

I believe this line always shows the SignIn page, never the progress indicator, since the data is always null there.

```
return snapshot.data == null ? SignIn() : Scaffold(body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),));
```

Try the following code:

```dart
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    if(snapshot.data == null) {
      return SignIn();
    } else {
      return snapshot.data == "no" ? SignIn() : Dashboard();
    }
  }
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),));
},
```

Comment: I tried this but when shared preference has no data then progress bar is keep on loading and no screen is rendered. @Manuel